# Where to make API call with Vue/Django project

Tags: django, vue.js

I have a Vue project and have previously used Django as a backend API only to access a database, but I have a project now where I reach out to the Yelp API. This API doesn't allow client-side(JS) API access because of CORS. Does it make sense that I would have to make an API call from Vue to Django to pass user input and then another API call from Django to Yelp.

This sounds like bad practice, but is there a better way to do this other than integrating a Django form to the page?

Comment: Making Yelp API requests from frontend is bad practice and the bad practice you have mentioned is actually **good practice**.

Comment: I agree with @RajaSimon